# Observer runs only once

Tags: magento, events

Event only runs once. I am adding custom value in quote after product add in cart through observer on **event checkout_quote_init**
    it works fine but if customer is logged in and place order then in first order value is inserted well in quote but in second time observer is not runing.

```
<checkout_quote_init>
    <observers>
        <youva_custom>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>custom/observer</class>
            <method>setqoutevalue</method>
        </youva_custom>
    </observers>
 </checkout_quote_init> 

 public function setqoutevalue($observer) {
     $event = $observer->getEvent();
     $_quote = $event->getQuote();
     $_quote->setCustomevalue($customevalue);
     $_quote->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the code that dispatches the event you are using you will see this (`Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::getQuote()`):

```
        if (!$this->getQuoteId()) {
            if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() || $this->_customer) {
                $customer = ($this->_customer) ? $this->_customer : $customerSession->getCustomer();
                $quote->loadByCustomer($customer);
                $this->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
            } else {
                $quote->setIsCheckoutCart(true);
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_quote_init', array('quote'=>$quote));
            }
        }
```

This means that the event is dispatched only when the quote is created. and only when the user is not logged in. This means that if there is already a quote id in the session the event won't get dispatched.

You may want to use a different event. For example `checkout_cart_product_add_after`